# Log Jenkins CLI Calls

Tags: logging, jenkins, jenkins-cli

i wonder if there s a way to log all CLI Calls.
Jenkins offers us to declare custom loggers in it s WebInterface and i was wondering if there s a option to take notice of any command line interactions.

So i tried to have a look at the Code but found nothing usefull.

```
hudson.cli.CLICommand is logging nearly nothing and the SubClasses too
hudson.cli.CliManagerImpl is logging exactly nothing
```

So i wonder if there s some kind of interceptor or a way to do this via groovy scripting?

kind regards
dag

PS:
My initial intention was to see if our scm backup script puts jenkins in shutdown mode during the night, but the Maintenance Logging of hudson.model.Queue is called much too often and i cant see if it is triggered just regulary or if it's through the quiet-down and cancel-quiet-down commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is three years old, but in case anyone finds it now (or in the future), as of Jenkins 2.129 this should be fixed (not releases yet). We had similar needs so we made an [issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52026) and [PR](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/3506) to fix it.

So, a lot more diagnostics will be written by setting the logger hudson.cli.CLICommand to FINE. [For more info on how to set logs have a look here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging).

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at the source code there was no way to do this via build in Loggers. But i was able so at least leave some Logs by using the groovy scripting interface.

Here s the example code for the quietDown Mode.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("jenkins.groovy.Maintenance")

logger.info ("User '" + jenkins.getAuthentication().getPrincipal() + "' requests doCancelQuietDown()")
jenkins.doCancelQuietDown()
```

Hope this helps someone.